# Why the Gayatri mantra is different in some words given to a Brahmin and Kshatriya?

Tags: vedas, gayatri-mantra

Why is Gayatri Mantra given to Brahmin and Kshatriya slightly different?

I was given this mantra from a Brahmin and the words are different such as

> ‘tat purusaya tanno surya, bidmahe’

These words are not mentioned in the mantras for Brahmin. Should not a mantra be the same since chanting is for same god?

Comment: Can you post the full mantra he gave you?

Comment: There is no such difference as per any authoritative scriptures IMHO

Comment: Not sure about why different for Brahmana and Kshatriya, but Gayathri Mantra is different for those who did not underwent Upanayana process. This different Gayatri Mantra introduced by Vyasa